# Can I discard parameters with a R-hat > 1.1 and consider the rest of parameters with a good R-hat value?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, glmm

I have a binomial glmm model containing many regressors. When summarizing the estimates, some parameters show R-hat > 1.1, indicating chains have not mixed and estimates should not be trusted as chains diverge between them.

I believe that the most appropiat solution should be to run the model entirely again with more iterations...

But, could parameters with a R-hat estimate > 1.1 just be simply disregarded/not trusted?

I am very new to this, so I would appreciate your guidance. I might be bullied after this last question (sorry :D)

Thank you in advance.
Cheers!

Comment: Maybe indeed a good idea to follow your intuition and start with running more iterations. In general, I don't know how much 'many regressors' are but you can consider trimming your model, also to reduce biases due to multicollinearity, overfitting, &c.

Comment: Many regressors range between 100-300...Sorry, by trimming you mean doing variable selection?

Comment: Indeed, trim the variable selection.